# Validate required field before swal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

How to validate required input field before swal?I have added required in input field but its not working?swal alerts are working fine,Anyone please help me to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="marks"  id="marks" required>
                                                         
    <button type="button" id="btn_upload<?php echo $s;?>" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="FunctionAdd(<?php echo $s;?>)" >Submit</button>
<script>
function FunctionAdd($s)
 {
swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "The data will input",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Add',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancel'
      }).then((result) => { 
        if (result.value) {alert('submitting');
        var myForm = $("#myForm"+$s)[0];
             $.ajax({
                 url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>creates",
                 type:"post",
                 data: new FormData(myForm),
                 processData:false,
                 contentType:false,
                 cache:false,
                 async:false,
                  success: function(data){
           window.location = '';

               },
               failure:function(d){
                      alert("Error")
                      alert(d)
               }
             });
          }
          
          else if (result.dismiss === 'cancel') {
                    swal(
                      'Cancelled',
                      'You stay here :)',
                      'error'
                    )
                }
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try triggering HTML5 form validation first using [HTMLFormElement.reportValidity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity)

```
function FunctionAdd($s) {
  var myForm = $("#myForm"+$s)[0];
  if (myForm.reportValidity()) {
    swal({
      ...
    }).then((result) => {
      ...
    });
  }
}
```